VS Code: new empty line after JS auto-complete accepted
Recently, I updated VS Code to the version 1.93.0-1725459079_amd64 (now 1.93.1-1726079302_amd64, but didn't fix the problem). I think I skipped some versions, but since the update, VS Code automatically inserts an empty line below the line I am coding in after accepting an auto-complete suggestion. The problem does not only occure when pressing enter, but also when pressing tab or when I click on the suggestion. (when coding in JavaScript, so I think the suggestions come from IntelliSense).
Here is an demonstration video
I searched the web a bit and tried changing a few settings like setting editor.suggest.insertMode to "replace", setting editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter to false, setting editor.suggestSelection to first, editor.tabCompletion to off and setting editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions to false. I also started VS Code without extensions using the command code --disable-extensions, but nothing seems to work. (some of it is advice from AI, so maybe it's not really fitting)
Maybe there is a new setting I don't know of?
I am happy to hear about every answer that could help :)

I think, that's the expected behavior. I can observe this in my VS Code. What's your question or the problem you want to solve? I would ask product or service related questions on the web site of the product or service. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues

I am just curious if there is a setting for this behavior you can turn off/change. When I add a console log between two lines, I do not want to have an empty line below the console log.

I think, the problem is with this specific auto-completion. I've tried other auto-completions and they they don't add a newline. That would mean, that it can't be configured with a global setting. These auto-completions replace your input with a template and it looks like the newline is in this template. You could perhaps fix this template.

I've found the JavaScript snippets in /usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/javascript/snippets, but this snippet doesn't contains a newline character. That's strange. Other snippets from this file don't create this newline, e.g. ctor or for but they create multiple lines containing at least one newline.

Now, I get it. The snippet configuration is "Log to the console":{"prefix":"log","body":["console.log($1);","$0"],"description":"Log to the console"}. Each element in the body array is a separate line. console.log($1);is the first line and $0 is the second line (the empty line). You could modify this snippet and e.g. remove $0. Here you can read more about it: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

The newline is part of the snippet. The snippet configuration is
"Log to the console":{"prefix":"log","body":["console.log($1);","$0"],"description":"Log to the console"}

inside
/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/javascript/snippets

on Linux. Each element in the body array is a separate line. $1 is the first tabstop and $0 is the final tabstop. That means, you can't configure this behavior globally in the configuration. You could modify this snippet
"Log to the console":{"prefix":"log","body":["console.log($0);"],"description":"Log to the console"}

or try to overwrite it.

You can easily define your own snippets without any extension. To create or edit your own snippets, select Configure User Snippets under File > Preferences (Code > Preferences or Code > Settings on macOS) , and then select the language (by language identifier) for which the snippets should appear, or the New Global Snippets file option if they should appear for all languages. VS Code manages the creation and refreshing of the underlying snippets file(s) for you.

More details and the syntax can be found at: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_snippet-syntax
